# Group of order 6 contains an element of of order 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to show that if $G$ is non-abelian group of order $6$ then it contains an element of order $3$. I don't know how to proceed. Any kind of help/hint is appreciated.

Comment: there are only two order six groups: $\Bbb Z_6$ and $S_3$

Comment: Hint:  suppose not.  Then every element (other than the identity) has order $2$.  Show that such a group is always abelian.

Comment: Can't you just use [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory))?

Comment: Why G is given to be non-abelian? What goes wrong in case of G being abelian?

Comment: The Sylow theorems tell you that there is a subgroup of order 3. As 3 is prime, each element which is not the neutral one in this subgroup is a generator of it.

Comment: @user311359  Do you know results like the Sylow Theorems?  If you do, then your question certainly follows quickly from them.  But your special case is a lot easier than the general theorem.  In my hint, I sketched one way to do it...I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, with the Sylow theorems the solution is trivial. So I would go with [lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu)'s hint: suppose not and show that such a group is always Abelian. Then every non-neutral element has order $2$. The key then is to be aware that for such an element $a$, $a^2 = e \implies a^{-1}=a$.
After that, a little fooling around with your elements will quickly solve your problem.

> $$\forall a,b \in G: (ab)(ab)^{-1} = e \implies abab = e \implies aba = b \implies ab = ba$$